# change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy in angular

Tags: html, datepicker

I want to change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy please look at the reference image once for clarity:

[image: Reference image]

**HTML**

```
<div fxFlex="calc(25% - 30px)">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
    <mat-label>Date of birth</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="date" [formControlName]="'dateOfBirth'" placeholder="Select entry date" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="dateFormat">
      <strong>Kindly enter a valid date</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
dateFormat: boolean;

validateDate() {
  if (this.memberForm.get('dateOfBirth').value == '') {
    this.dateFormat = true;
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.validateDate();
}
```

Comment: You are using [input type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) which has some limitations. It's stated there that "the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser"
And there seems to be no way to customize it, so I guess you can't use the browser's native datepicker with that requirements. However, the `value` behind has always the same format.

Comment: means cant we change that default date format which was created by angular people?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. As I said, you are using the browser's native date input field, which has the limitations I mentioned. Either you live with it, or you need to use a completely different component, e.g. [Angular Material's Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){}
...
myFunction(){
this.date=new Date();
let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

and just add Datepipe in 'providers' array of app.module.ts. Like this:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Comment: sorry not working could you please provide a solution in stackblitz